# Как вырезать кадр из видео python?

Tags: python, видео

Есть ли способ вырезать кадр из видео? Пробовал `moviepy` и `ffmpeg` к сожалению они работают слишком медленно.

Comment: вопрос 'как' или вопрос 'быстро' ? в какое время нужно уложиться ?

Comment: @Интик Нужен максимально быстрый способ.